# How does git manage conflicting differences?

Tags: git

For example, let's say that two users pull the same version of a project. Both users write the same function, but do it in different ways. User A commits their work and pushes to the master branch. User B then commits and attempts to push to the master branch. Won't there be an issue, as there are now two versions of the same function?

Forgive me if this is vague or a dumb question, as I really have no idea what I'm doing with version control at all (git is my first).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, User A and User B must each have their own repositories. Since they are working together, they can also have a central repository in some shared location where they can share changes. (Alternatively, they can push and pull directly from each other's repositories.) When User B attempts to push his changes, though, git will not allow it. He will need to perform a merge first and manually resolve any conflicts.

Comment: Hmm, alright, thanks. I guess that my question was more about how large teams manage to dish out work to all contributors rather than how git does things. This is a good answer to the question though, so I'll accept it.

Comment: @JohnLeuenhagen You might consider posting that question on [Programmers.SE] which has more to do with Software Engineering.

Comment: @JohnLeuenhagen: I've asked this question a number of times of several different people.  The best answer I seem to be getting is "don't allow two people to work on the same class at the same time."

Comment: @RobertHarvey, sure, that trivializes the issue. I see no problem in having people work on the same unit of code in parallel as long as there is clear communication. People do have their separate repositories after all, they can keep clean development processes no matter what (i.e. commit often, etc.). Hopefully, there is a common issue tracker to see what actually needs to be done. Problems can only occur during merge time, and then the developers in question can hopefully figure it out!

Comment: @AnoE: Meh.  Why would two people ever work on the same lines of code at the same time?  (most merge utilities, including Git's, are supposed to automatically merge lines that have nothing to do with each other).  That merge conflicts happen at all is a planning problem, not a Git problem (overall, merging sucks).

Comment: Trivializing the issue seems to be a good solution to me. Why make things more difficult than necessary? As you say, good communication is necessary when working as a team. In this particular example, good communication will guarantee that work is not being duplicated. There is no good reason to have two different programmers working on the same function. This just duplicates effort that could be more effectively assigned in other ways.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of here. "Overall, merging sucks" - alright then.

Answer (score 2):

> I guess that my question was more about how large teams manage to dish out work to all contributors rather than how git does things.

"Rather than how git does things" implies that you believe git is not the correct tool for large teams. On the contrary... look at where git comes from; it is a very good tool for exactly that, simply because it was written with large teams and large code bases in mind.

The answer to your quoted question is twofold:

First, the fact that `git push` forces you to do a `git pull` first is a very clear way to handle things. There will never be any accidental pushes; a push is always (unless you specify `-f`, which can be disabled serverside) trivial, or in git language, a "fast forward".

Second; the way large teams normally work is by having feature branches; this means work is doled out in small(ish) pieces, each of which exists as a separate branch in the `git` repositories. If you are lucky, the normal case will be that each branch is in development by one person only. If you must indeed work on a branch with several developers, then at least any kind of conflict resolution involves only this small subset of the total of developers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full details about the diff algorithms:
git used diff2 or diff3 based upon configuration

For general knowledge here specs for diff2 & diff3.

diff2: http://www.xmailserver.org/diff2.pdf
diff3: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/papers/diff3-short.pdf

Comment: Useful, but isn't there a bit more of a simple explanation? Would some work be lost if there are conflicts?